# Why is this jquery method not returning SELECTED value?

Tags: jquery, methods, return

My jquery method WILL not return value "Selected". My alert shows that the value is retrived from database. But if I write data=GetSelected(); it is undefined...

```
 function GetSelected()
 {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/api/machine/',
         dataType: "JSON",
         data: "data",
         error: function (error) { },
         success: function (data)
         {
            $.each(data, function (i, data)
            {
                 if (data.machinenumber == 2)
                {       
                     selected = data.selected;
                     alert('Selected er: ' + selected)
                     return selected;
                 };

            });

         } 
     }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement belongs to the `function(i, data)` header in the for-each loop, not the `function (data)` header that is getting executed on success. Basically the values gets returns to the outer function and ignored there.

Comment: Also the logic is asynchronous, so the above also happens long after the `GetSelected()` function has exited.

Comment: Like that?   $.each(function (i, data)...Did not work.

Comment: Oh..I remenber something about a callback function inside my function